# Ajax load data in datatables and set data on button

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

everything works fine. The only issue that i cannot fix/find is how to create a button and set the value of data: cvpdf inside a href of a button to open the cv
The cvpdf is the file name of a cv stored in the database.

```
   <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped custom-table mb-0 datatable " >
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>surname</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th>position</th>
              <th>CV</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="atn-tbody">
      </tbody>
  </table>


  function showInformation(str)  {
    console.log(str);
    $("#dtBasicExample").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#dtBasicExample").dataTable({
          scrollX: true,
            "ajax":{
            url: "data.php?q="+str ,
            dataSrc:"",
           
           },
           "columns":[
         {"data": "id"},
           {"data": "name"},
           {"data": "surname"},
           {"data": "email"},
           {"data": "position"},
           {"data": "cvpdf"},
           ]    
          });  
        }); 
};
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck, exactly? For example, forgetting about DataTables, can you create a hard-coded HTML button to open one (arbitrary) CV PDF? If so, can you show us that code - because that is effectively a template for what you want to create in each cell of your table's `CV` column. You can then use a DataTables [renderer](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to build that button in each cell, inserting the correct `cvpdf` value.

Comment: Or maybe you are getting stuck somewhere else?

Comment: The user first uploads the CV and it is stored to the database. Then when the admin goes to the USER panel he sees the users with the CV. I couldn't make a button to insert the cv name so it opens directly. I don't know how to make one because its ajax request. Can you help? @andrewJames

Comment: Can you create a hard-coded HTML button to open one (arbitrary) CV PDF? (See my first comment).

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you out with this. you can apply this to any column data

```
columns: [
    {
       data: function(row){
           return `<a href="${row.cvpdf}">Click This</a>`
       }
    }
]
```

the "row" parameter will return the whole data for the current row, so you can access the object through the "row.your_key".

this is the best practice to make your code simpler.

the complete parameter can be accessed through [This Link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)

Hope it can help!